# No longer able to convert Ecto.DateTime.to_erl

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

My goal is to find time difference in minutes:

```
 {_, {_, aaa, _}} = Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(d1) |> :calendar.time_difference(:calendar.universal_time)
```

I have a timestamp retrieved from Postgresql:

```
iex(13)> d1
~N[2017-02-09 07:23:04.000000]
```

Previously this worked well:

```
d11 = Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(d1)
```

But now it throws an exception:

```
* (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.DateTime.to_erl/1
    (ecto) lib/ecto/date_time.ex:608: Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(~N[2017-02-09 07:23:04.000000])
```

How to fix that?

I'm not willing to use external libraries such as times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the `DateTime` value you have in RDBMS lacks the timezone information. There is a main difference between [`Ecto.DateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#content) and [`NaiveDateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html): the former cares about timezones, and the latter does not (as well as standard erlang datetime.)

```
iex(1)> d1 = ~N[2017-02-09 07:23:04.000000]
~N[2017-02-09 07:23:04.000000]
iex(2)> NaiveDateTime.to_erl d1
{{2017, 2, 9}, {7, 23, 4}}
```

From the snippet above one might see, that the conversion is still possible with [`NaiveDateTime.to_erl/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#to_erl/1).

The core solution would be to find the cause of having naïve datetime value in the RDBMS and fix it.

Comment: I don't know, but now it returns it in the Naive format.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, RDBMS does not **produce** values, it returns exactly what was stored. That said, somewhere in the application you store a naïve value there. I strongly suggest you to find the cause, otherwise you’ll definitely have problems with this matter on a long run.

Comment: previously it saved datetime in a database without milliseconds, now with -- with 6 digits after coma in the "seconds" part. do you have any idea why?

Comment: I know what milliseconds is, and no, I am not a fortuneteller. You should examine your code that operates data and performs writes.

Comment: postgresql itself doesn't store timezone information, does it? it merely stores all timestamps in utc.

Comment: ну, что я говорил "warning: the :datetime type in migrations is deprecated, please use :utc_datetime or :naive_datetime instead" -- так что это не мой код виноват.